# Find the value of $y(1)$ of the ODE $y'+y=|x|$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y$ be the solution of $$y'+y=|x|$$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $y(-1)=0$.
Then the value of $y(1)$ is

1. $\frac{2}{e}-\frac{2}{e^2}$
2. $\frac{2}{e}-2e^2$
3. $2-\frac{2}{e}$
4. $2-2e$

I don't know what to do with the absolute value function in this problem. So I started like the regular first order equation by calculating integrating factor, and got
$$ye^x=\int |x|e^x dx+C.$$ Now I got stuck as how to tackle the absolute value function? Help me to solve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 
$$y(x)\exp(x)=\int_{-1}^x |t|\exp(t)dt+y(-1)\exp(-1)$$
As $y(-1)=0$, we have $\displaystyle y(1)e=\int_{-1}^1 |t|\exp(t)dt$. Now write $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^1|t|\exp(t)dt=\int_{-1}^0|t|\exp(t)dt+\int_0^1|t|\exp(t)dt$.

Comment: How did you get $y(-1)\exp(-1)$ term in the first equation?

Comment: Write $y(x)\exp(x)=\int_{-1}^x |t|\exp(t)dt+c$, and then put $x=-1$.

Comment: Got it ..thanks

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

For $x<0$, the equation $y'+y=-x$ gives $y(x)=A.e^{-x} + 1-x$ as its solution. As $y(-1)=0→A=-2/e$. Hence $y(x)=(-2/e).e^{-x} +1-x$ is solution for $x<0$ from which you get $y(0-)=1-2/e$.

For $x\ge 0$, the equation $y'+y=x$ gives $y(x)=B.e^{-x}+x-1$ as its solution. As $y(x) $must be continuous so $y(0)=y(0-)\implies B-1=1-2/e\implies B=2-2/e$. Now, $y(x)=(2-2/e).e^{-x}+x-1$ is solution for $x\ge 0$. Then $y(1)=2/e - 2/e^2$.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the case $x\geq 0$ first and solve it. Then, solve for the case $x<0$. Then, you get two solutions, called $y^+(x)$ and $y^-(x)$. Since the solution is continuous, you have a condition $y^+(0)=y^-(0)$. Besides, you have $y^-(-1)=0$. Then, you can solve the constants in the equations and get the value $y(1)=y^+(1)$.