# $y$ be the solution of $y'+y=|x|,x\in \mathbb{R}$, find $y(1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y$  be the solution of $$y'+y=|x|,x\in \mathbb{R}$$
$$y(-1)=0$$ 
Then what is the value of $y(1)$:

Efforts:

I know how to solve the linear equations of general form $$y'+Py=Q$$ where $P$ and $Q$ are continuous function of $x$.

In my case $P=1$ and $Q=|x|$ and both are continuous.

Now  if I apply the formula I get

$$ye^x=\int e^x |x|dx+C$$

Now if I put the initial value I get $$0=\int e^{-1}dx+C$$

Now what should I do? I mean what should be the range of integration and how I proceed from here.

Thanks.

Comment: I have voted my question as duplicate. I have found the solution here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1850959/find-the-value-of-y1-of-the-ode-yy-x I am not deleting it as it has received two upvotes and one favorites. Thanks

Comment: "Now if I put the initial value I get" What? Come again? What do you think the formula just after that even means?

Comment: @Did Can you explain? I did not get it

Comment: Again, what do you mean by "Now if I put the initial value I get $0=\int e^{-1}dx+C$"? Can you explain? I do not get it.

Answer (score 0):

In general terms, the solution of

$y' + Py = Q, \; y(-1) = 0, \tag 1$

may be derived as follows:

$\exp \left (\displaystyle \int_{x_0}^x P(s)\; ds \right ) y' + \exp \left (\displaystyle \int_{x_0}^x P(s)\; ds \right )  Py = \exp \left (\displaystyle \int_{x_0}^x P(s)\; ds \right )Q; \tag 2$

$\left ( \exp \left (\displaystyle \int_{x_0}^x P(s)\; ds \right )y \right )' = \exp \left (\displaystyle \int_{x_0}^x P(s)\; ds \right )Q; \tag 3$

$\exp \left (\displaystyle \int_{x_0}^x P(s)\; ds \right )y(x) - y(x_0) =\displaystyle  \int_{x_0}^x  \exp \left (\displaystyle \int_{x_0}^u P(s)\; ds \right )Q(u) \; du; \tag 4$

$y(x) = \exp \left (-\displaystyle \int_{x_0}^x P(s)\; ds \right )\left ( y(x_0) + \displaystyle  \int_{x_0}^x  \exp \left (\displaystyle \int_{x_0}^u P(s)\; ds \right )Q(u) \; du \right ); \tag 5$

in the present case,

$y' + y = \vert x \vert, \; y(-1) = 0; \tag 6$

$P(x) = 1, \; Q(x) = \vert x \vert; \tag 7$

$\displaystyle \int_{x_0}^x P(s) \; ds = x - x_0; \tag 8$

$\exp \left ( \displaystyle \int_{x_0}^x P(s)\; ds \right ) = e^{x - x_0}; \tag 9$

with

$x_0 = -1, \; y(x_0) = y(-1) = 0 \tag{10}$

we find

$\exp \left ( \displaystyle \int_{-1}^x P(s)\; ds \right ) = e^{x + 1}, \tag{11}$

$\exp \left (- \displaystyle \int_{-1}^x P(s)\; ds \right ) = e^{-(x + 1)}, \tag{12}$

and from (5),

$y(x) = e^{-(x + 1)} \displaystyle  \int_{-1}^x e^{u + 1} \vert u \vert \; du = e^{-x} \displaystyle  \int_{-1}^x e^u \vert u \vert \; du ; \tag{13}$

with $x \ge 0$,

$\displaystyle  \int_{-1}^x e^u \vert u \vert \; du = \int_{-1}^0 (-ue^u) \; du + \int_0^x ue^u \; du = \int_0^x ue^u \; du - \int_{-1}^0 ue^u \; du; \tag{14}$

the integrals of the form occurring in (14) are well-known; indeed the anti-derivative of $ue^u$ is found from

$(e^u(u - 1))' = e^u(u - 1) + e^u = ue^u; \tag{15}$

it then follows that

$\displaystyle \int_a^b ue^e \; u = (e^u(u - 1)]_a^b =e^b(b - 1) - e^a(a - 1) = be^b - ae^a -(e^b - e^a); \tag{16}$

we thus may evaluate (14):

$\displaystyle \int_0^x ue^u \; du - \int_{-1}^0 ue^u \; du$
$= (xe^x - e^x + 1) - (e^{-1} -1 + e^{-1}) = xe^x - e^x + 2 - 2e^{-1}; \tag{17}$

thus, from (13),

$y(x) = x - 1 + 2e^{-x} - 2e^{-1 - x}; \tag{18}$

finally we find

$y(1) = 2e^{-1} - 2e^{-2}. \tag{19}$